# Google Maps without Google API build target?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm developing an Android app that I want to use Google Maps. As far as I'm aware, I can't implement Maps unless I set Google API as the build target. When I do that, however, Eclipse erases my R.java file and won't regenerate it after a clean. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I'm aware, I can't implement Maps unless I set Google API as the build target.

Correct.

> When I do that, however, Eclipse erases my R.java file and won't regenerate it after a clean. Is there any way around this?

Fix the problems in your resources and manifest that are preventing `R.java` from being generated. You can:

- look for the red X's in the Package Explorer
- look in the Problems view
- do a command-line build

to try to track these down.